# Tensorflow, ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow

When trying to train my tensorflow graph im getting the error message:

> ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

happening in this line of code, in the feed_dict function:

```
# run the session and train the model
        _, c = sess.run([optimizer, cost], feed_dict = {input_x: x_train_v, output_y: y_train})
```

It seems to be a problem with my output variable (y_train). It is a List of size(25) inside a pandas dataframe. 
Already checked if every list has the same length with

```
print(y_train.shape) #(23904,)
print(y_train.apply(type)[0]) #<class 'list'>

n = len(y_train[0])
if all(len(x) == n for x in y_train):
    print("true")  #true
```

The variable is created with following code:

```
dataframe['category_number'] = ""
for _ in range(len(dataframe)):
    string = dataframe.at[_, 'Product Categorization Tier 1'].strip()
    number = category_list.index(string)   
    # saving as category vector
    vector = [0] * 25 
    vector[number] = 1
    dataframe.at[_,'category_number'] = vector

y_train = train_df["category_number"]
```

**Edit:**
Cost Function and Optimizer

```
prediction = neural_network_model(input_x )
cost = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=prediction, labels=output_y))
optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(learning_rate).minimize(cost)
```

Full Error Message:
[image]

Comment: `print(y_train.apply(type)[0]) #<class 'list'>` I think you expect int here?

Comment: I expect it to be a List, because its the vector for the labels of the output and my NN should have 25 Neurons in the output layer, like the lenght of the list

Comment: So it's a one-hot-vector for classification. does your loss expect a scalar? E: can you print the whole stracktrace?

Comment: Yes right, it is a one-hot-vector. I added my cost function and the full error message

Comment: If it's a one-hot-vector, isn't `print(y_train.shape)` supposed to return (23904,25) ?

Comment: yes actually that is kinda curious, I think it has to do something with the data representation in the dataframe. When printing it it looks fine for me: https://imgur.com/a/aPdNeSL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like

```
y_train = []
for _ in range(len(dataframe)):
    string = dataframe.at[_, 'Product Categorization Tier 1'].strip()
    number = category_list.index(string)   
    # saving as category vector
    vector = [0] * 25 
    vector[number] = 1
    y_train.append(vector)
```

And make sure you get a 2d-int array and not an array of objects

Comment: okay, I will try it. The reason I returned it as Dataframe row, was because I actually was splitting the data afterwards into train and test set. Think I have to find another way to do so

Comment: seems to work, can't tell now cause a training epoch seems to take hours